# Prevent Firefox from opening svg images in a new tab on middle mouse click

Tags: javascript, events, firefox, svg, raphael

I'm currently working on a javascript project, where I put svg images on my RaphaelJS svg canvas using the Paper.image function (see here: http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.image).
For certain actions the user has to click with the middle mouse button. However, when the user clicks (with the middle mouse button) on an included svg image, Firefox opens the image in a new tab. (Chrome doesn't do this)
As I want to deny this behavior I tried to call

```
function(e) {e.preventDefault();}
```

as onclick event, but this doesn't change Firefox's behavior.

http://jsfiddle.net/M7K2q/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well in fact you the ability to open an image by middle click is considered a "feature" of Firefox.

**BUT!**
 You can expose the image as a background of other elements such as a rectangle and obtain the same effect.

```
 var paper = Raphael("canvas", 400, 400);
 paper.rect(0, 0, 114, 40.6).attr({
    fill: "url(https://www.google.com/logos/2011/twain11-sr.png)"
 }).attr({ stroke: '' });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/saxxi/9BcDd/1/